# i dont know what this means: error cs0426

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I saw this tutorial for making 1 person game:
https://youtu.be/rJqP5EesxLk

And I get this error:

> Error CS0426: The type name 'OnFootActions' does not exist in the type 'PlayerInput'

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class InputManger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;

    private PlayerMotor motor;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        PlayerInput = new PlayerInput();
        onFoot = PlayerInput.OnFoot;
        motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // tell the playermotor to move using the value from our movement action.
        motor.ProcessMove(onFoot.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>());    
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        onFoot.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        onFoot.Disable();
   }
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure when setting up the new input system you named everything exactly? Confessing im not going to watch a tutorial just to answer a question it looks like something that is setup there.

Comment: Did you enable the `generat c#` option? Are you sure you named the asset, maps and actions exactly the same way as in the tutorial? Did you hit `Save Asset`?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```cs
private PlayerInput playerInput;
```

is declaring a variable of type `PlayerInput`, so you would need a type something like this:

```cs
public class PlayerInput
{
    // ...
}
```

This line:

```cs
private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;
```

is declaring a variable of type `PlayerInput.OnFootActions`, which means a type named `OnFootActions` nested inside the `PayerInput` class, like this:

```cs
public class PlayerInput
{
    public class OnFootActions
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

The error message is telling you that there is no such nested class. Why that is, we don't know. I won't be watching the whole tutorial to find out. Make sure that you have used the correct type for that variable and declared the appropriate type(s) if you are supposed to. If you have followed their instructions and it still doesn't work, the tutorial is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that Unity imports a class named `PlayerInput` when you import the Input System from Package Manager. This `PlayerInput` class is conflicting with your `PlayerInput` Class. Meaning Unity takes `PlayerInput` from InputSystem that doesn't have the `OnFootActions` class instead of the auto-generated script `PlayerInput` you made.

---

To fix this, you can simply rename the **InputActionAsset**.

So, this

```cs
private PlayerInput playerInput;
private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;
```

becomes:

```cs
private NewName newName;
private NewName.OnFootActions onFoot;
```

Comment: i tried to change the name to ThePlayer, and its gave me more errors:                               
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ThePlayerInput' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You will need to update the references too. In other words, rename find and replace "PlayerInput" with "ThePlayer". Also delete the autogenerated script, because it might cause some errors.

Comment: thank you, but it didnt work, because unity show the same errors with the name "ThePlayer".